# RNeo4j; match on two node labels

Tags: neo4j, r-neo4j

I have two different *types* of nodes; 'Elements' and 'Aspects'. All nodes have a unique numerical ID, irrespective of *type*.

If I want to add relationships between the 'Element' nodes, I could do;

```
    query = "MATCH (e:Element {id:{exp}}),(o:Element {id:{out}}) CREATE (e)-[:IVW]->(o);"
```

and then use a for loop to assign `exp` and `out` from a dataframe in R. I could do the same thing for relationships between 'Aspect' nodes. But what about if I want to assign relationships between *all* nodes in a single command. I am looking for a single command which will do the following four commands;

```
query = "MATCH (e:Element {id:{exp}}),(o:Element {id:{out}}) CREATE (e)-[:IVW]->(o);"
query = "MATCH (e:Aspect {id:{exp}}),(o:Aspect {id:{out}}) CREATE (e)-[:IVW]->(o);"
query = "MATCH (e:Element {id:{exp}}),(o:Aspect {id:{out}}) CREATE (e)-[:IVW]->(o);"
query = "MATCH (e:Aspect {id:{exp}}),(o:Element {id:{out}}) CREATE (e)-[:IVW]->(o);"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
query = "MATCH (e1:Element {id:{exp}}),(e2:Element {id:{out}}),
(a1:Aspect {id:  {exp}}),(a2:Aspect {id:{out}}) 
CREATE (e1)-[:IVW]->(e2),(a1)-[:IVW]->(a2),(e1)-[:IVW]->(a2),(a1)-[:IVW]->(e2)"
```